# Не работает require_once на сервере

Tags: php, linux, include

Привет. Странное поведение на сервере.

Код

`require_once '/classes/mysql.php';`

возвращает ошибку

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/site/data/www/site.com/engine/classes/mysql.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in
>   /var/www/site/data/www/site.ru/get_subsection.php on line 26

А если заменю на

`include_once /classes/mysql.php';`

то все работает.

CentOS. PHP 5.3

Что может быть не так настроено на сервере?

Comment: Путь так и прописан в функции? `/classes/mysql.php'`

Comment: Нет, иначе бы инклуд не работал тоже. Кавычку забыл когда поста писал. Поправил.

Comment: Кажется include просто плюнет предупреждение и поедет дальше.  А предупреждения вы возможно игнорируете

Comment: @ПавелЖуковский, сделайте относительный путь от вызывающего файла к вызываемому, а не путь от корня сайта (стартовый слеш).

Answer (score 2):

Проблема оказалась в правах доступа к файлу. Хоть файл и был, но у пользователя не было права доступа его читать. Переключил сервер в режим FastCGI и все заработало.